# Variable target in Makefile based on conditional

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to use make to manage my dev machines across platforms. I would like to check if `ipython` is installed on the machine and if not install it. The path that `ipython` installed is different between OSX and Linux.

I have tried setting a variable like below but it seems like variable is ignored (possibly out of scope?).

```
ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Linux)
    IPYTHON_BIN=/usr/bin/ipython
endif
ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Darwin)
    IPYTHON_BIN=/usr/local/bin/ipython
endif

ipython: $(IPYTHON_BIN) $(IPYTHON_CONFIG)

$(IPYTHON_BIN):
    pip install ipython
```

Is there another way to accomplish this or is there another simple fix?

Comment: Are those both in your `$PATH`? Do you care what the path actually is or just that it works? What do you mean "ignored"? What happens exactly? What does `make` output? What does `make -rRd` output?

Comment: They will be on the `$PATH` once installed. I don't care what the path is. Output from `make ipython`: http://pastebin.com/8yT5giD6

Comment: What is `$(UNAME_S)`? Can you add `$(info [$(UNAME_S)])` to your makefile and run `make ipython` again (no need for `-rRd` this time).

Answer (score 0):

You may have ommitted the code where you attempt to assign the name of
your operating system to `UNAME_S`, and done it wrongly. Or possibly you
are under the mistaken impression that the name of your OS is being automatically
assigned to `UNAME_S` in your environment.

Anyway you would achieve what you want with:

```
UNAME_S := $(shell uname -s)
ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Linux)
    IPYTHON_BIN:=/usr/bin/ipython
endif
ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Darwin)
    IPYTHON_BIN:=/usr/local/bin/ipython
endif
ifndef IPYTHON_BIN
$(error Unknown OS)
endif
...
....
```

which will also cause `make` to error out with:

```
*** Unknown OS. Stop
```

if your OS is not in the supported set.